# Is it possible to create a tooltip that appears when the mouse is hovered over text inside <p> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, web, tooltip

I am using a website builder (Weebly) and I want to make it so that when certain words on my webpage (which are somehow highlighted - bold, a different colour or whatever) are hovered over, a tooltip appears with a definition of that word.

Weebly does give me the option to embed code on the page, but not within a paragraph.  So is there any way for me to set up the page so that definitions can be made to appear when the mouse hovers over certain words within p tags?

The other option is to hyperlink the words to anchors on a separate Glossary page, however this is messy because it will force the user to click the back button on their browser etc., and it will also take a long time to set up all the hyperlinks and anchors.

I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: You can encapsulate the words in spans and give them a title attribute. Like this: `<span title="Model View Controller">MVC</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate the words in spans and give them a title attribute. 
Like this: `<span title="Model View Controller">MVC</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `abbr` TAG

```
<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>
```

Browsers should automatically show tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Weebly, but provided you can do some basic scripting, the process is fairly straightforward:

Here are a few snippets to get you going.

HTML:

```
<p>The brown fox jumped over the <a href="#" title="This is the definition">lazy</a> dog.</p>
```

JS (Using the [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) library):

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention, that jQuery and jQueryUI are needed for this to work.

Comment: This actually worked without me having to use the JS, so I assume that the script is already installed somewhere in Weebly's backend.

Thanks!